# Only executing a worksheet change when a cell goes from blank to populated

Tags: excel, vba

I came across an issue when I was trying to number a new Item in a list and populate the relevant default values in that same row for the relevant columns. I don't want the cells in the other columns to change if the cell was already populated with data. i.e. if the target cell in the target column has information in it and someone edits the information I don't want it to erase the information in the other columns for that row.

I have written the following code to achieve this, but I am not sure how to check if the target cell has text inside already as what I have tried has not worked (If IsEmpty(Target.Value) = True Then).

```
If IsEmpty(Target.Value) = True Then

Dim Description_Column_No As Integer
Dim Default_Start As String

'Inputs
Default_Start = "N/A"
Description_Column_No = 3

'Output Columns
Output_Col_Item = Description_Column_No - 1
Output_Col_1 = Description_Column_No + 6
Output_Col_2 = Description_Column_No + 18
Output_Col_3 = Description_Column_No + 28
Output_Col_4 = Description_Column_No + 38
Output_Col_5 = Description_Column_No + 44
Output_Col_6 = Description_Column_No + 55
Output_Col_7 = Description_Column_No + 62


'Adding the date to the relevant cell

'Setting the Item Number for the new Item
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_Item).Value = Target.Row - 5
End With

'Setting the dropdowns to default values

With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_1).Value = Default_Start
End With
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_2).Value = Default_Start
End With
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_3).Value = Default_Start
End With
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_4).Value = Default_Start
End With
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_5).Value = Default_Start
End With
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_6).Value = Default_Start
End With
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_7).Value = Default_Start
End With

End If
```

Comment: Perhaps use `IsEmpty` on the *other* cells in the row, not `Target`.

Comment: I want to have it set up so that the user just has to enter the name of the item and then it is automatically assigned a number and the default columns are populated. so it is really only that cell that I want to apply the code to.

Comment: "I don't want the cells in the other columns to change if the cell was already populated with data."... Then you have to check the *other* cells before modifying them.

Comment: Good Idea! I tried: If IsEmpty(Me.Range(Status_Col_2 & Target.Row)) = True Or IsEmpty(Me.Range(Status_Col_2 & Target.Row)) = True Then

Comment: I got no code errors but the code doesn't do anything, when I change the cell value. there is no way of stepping through the code as it is a worksheet change, is that right?

Comment: What is `Status_Col_2`? (not in your current code snippet).

Comment: sorry that is just the column letter in this case "T", but I tried IsEmpty(Me.Range("T" & Target.Row)) = True and that didnt make a difference

Comment: My recommendation was to check the `Output_Col` columns so I'm not sure why you're using `Status_Col` or if the status col is different than the output columns. This is assuming that the `Output_Col` columns are empty until they are populated when `Target` changes. If that's not the case, then you have to keep track of the "previous" value in the `Target` cell, which you can do using a `Selection_Change` event, `Workbook_Open` event and a `Public` variable.

Comment: Your With blocks are all structured oddly so that may be part of the problem - the blocks have no content, since the line-continuation makes the "content" part of the `With`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking this first:

```
With _
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_1).Value = Default_Start
End With
```

this is an empty `With` block (more obvious if you remove the `_`)

```vba
With Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_1).Value = Default_Start
   'nothing here...
End With
```

This:

```
Target(Target.Row, Output_Col_1)
```

is the same as

```
Target.Cells(Target.Row, Output_Col_1)
```

but might produce unexpected results as `Cells()` is always run *relative to the object it's called on*, so for example if `Target` is (eg) B5 then the expression above is the same as `[B5].Cells(5, 9)` or J9...

Lastly, when the `With` block runs, what looks like a value *assignment* ("set range value to 'N/A'") is run as a value *comparison* ("is the range value 'N/A' ?")  , so it doesn't result in any update to your sheet.

That said, it feels like we're missing some context from the rest of the not-shown code, but your posted code can be improved/condensed:

```vba
Const DESCR_COL As Long = 3
Const DEFAULT_VAL As String = "N/A"

Dim v, c As Range
'...
'...
If IsEmpty(target.Value) Then
    With target.EntireRow
        .Cells(DESCR_COL - 1).Value = .Row - 5
        For Each v In Array(6, 18, 28, 38, 44, 55, 62)
            Set c = .Cells(DESCR_COL + v)
            If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Value = DEFAULT_VAL
        Next v
    End With
End If
```

Using the Row number to assign an "Id" is a problem though - re-sorting or inserting/deleting rows will cause problems for the next entry.

Comment: this alternative code worked great, I just had to add "not" to the start of "If IsEmpty(target.Value) Then" and change the column numbers by -1. Thank you for the elegant solution!